# Show a certain amount of unique values of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I’ve got an array like:

```
$names = array(
    "Skyler",
    "Jesse",
    "Walter",
    "Skyler",
    "Hank",
    "Marie",
    "Walter",
    "Walter",
    "Jesse",
    );
```

To check how often an equal value is in my array, 
I count them with `array_count_values`.
To order the list by frequency of each value I use `arsort`:

```
$count = array_count_values($names);

foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' – ' . $key . '<br />';
}
```

So I get this:

```
3 – Walter
2 – Skyler
2 – Jesse
1 – Hank
1 – Marie
```

Now I’d like to show only the 3 values with the highest frequency, so Walter, Jesse and Skyler. But I don’t know how … Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$count = array_count_values($names);
arsort($count, SORT_NUMERIC);
$result = array_slice($count, 0, 3);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into `array_slice()`.

```
$highest = array_slice($count, 0, 3);
```

This returns the first three elements of that array. Documentation can be found **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    if($i == 3){
        break;
    }
    echo $value . ' – ' . $key . '<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Can't hardcode '3' as number of times a element occurs may vary

Comment: i don't get your idea. this $count already is resort by max, so the first three element is what he need. i think array_slice is better. but i'm just take question owner code as is.